# Click a specific hidden button (multiple have the same name) using Selenium but I can match the specific table the button is within

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

There's a hidden configure button until you scroll over it within multiple sections of an admin console for Gsuite and they all have the same class value and text. I know the specific section (content compliance) I want with a configure button but I'm not really sure how pinpoint down to the hidden button.

I've tried to do something along the lines of this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'gwt-Label title-widget') and .//text()='Content compliance'] and //div[contains(@class, 'NYMEHID-pd-m' and .//text()='Configure']").click()
```

But I'm pretty new to selenium and xpath so I don't think that's actually searching properly or selenium is even able to see the configure button until a mouse scrolls over it. Any help would be welcome, thanks.

```
<tr style="">
<td class="title-column">
    <div>
        <div class="gwt-Label title-widget">Content compliance</div>
        <div class="gwt-Label disabled-email-setting-label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">Disabled</div>
        <div class="gwt-Label disabled-email-setting-label" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="gwt-Label inherit-label">Not configured yet</div>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="column-content">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="gwt-Label">Configure advanced content filters based on words, phrases or patterns.</div>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="column-content inherit-column">
    <div class="settingGroupActionPopupBase visuallyHidden">
        <div class="settingGroupActionPopupPanel">
            <button type="button" class="quantumButton quantumButton-raised">
                <div>
                    <div class="NYMEHID-pd-d" style="display:none" title="Configure"></div>
                    <div class="NYMEHID-pd-m" style="display: block;">Configure</div>
                    <div class="NYMEHID-pd-e" style="left: -48px; top: -91px;"></div>
                    <div class="NYMEHID-pd-f" style="left: -48px; top: -91px;"></div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Try JavaScript's scrollIntoView function, `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', driver._find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()='Configure']'));`

Comment: So that works to scroll to the first configure but there's 12 or so hidden configures on this page. I was trying to specific to basically go to the Content compliance one and click the next configure in the chain. Will play around with that functionality though! Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise you can try doing mouse over using `actions` and moving to the desired element and clicking on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check if this work, if you have multiple elements with same name.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='quantumButton quantumButton-raised']")
for element in elements:
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element);
 print('Pass')
```

Comment: Hey this works! Trying to figure out how to specify to click a specific one however. Right now it clicks the first quantum button on the list.

Comment: Sorry yeah. I was trying to figure out something since it needs to be slightly modified. That defined 15 elements and I only want element 6 to be clicked so I was working through it. But yeah yours is a great base to work from. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.Please click on accept button of my code message.There is an accept button.

Comment: thanks for the help! using your piece then modifying it the for statement to the below got it to get what I wanted.
    for element in elements[5:6]

Comment: Great.Let me know if you need any further help.